# shared objects in redhat linux

Tags: linux, shared, redhat, shared-objects

Hello everybody 
well i just had a problem With Shared Object (.so) in REDHAT linux
what i want to know is : if i put a new SO in /Lib or /lib64 wich are in the $PATH shal i reboot the server or not...
NB : The server is in production and i don't want to reboot it when it's not necessary 
best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to reboot.  If you put a .so in a non-standard path you may want to list that path in /etc/ld.config or in a file in /etc/ld.config.d and run ldconfig, otherwise users will need to have that path in their LD_LIBRARY_PATH (PATH is irrelevant). If you put the .so in /lib or /lib64, you shouldn't need to do anything else.